# how to put text btween html tag with python webdriver

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

How to put text between html tag with python WebDriver?

```
<!--html cod-->
<span class="py"></span>  
<!--I want to put text between span tag with python WebDriver like this-->
<span class="py">text</span>
```

Comment: @orde: that question has to do with inserting text in a DOM element; this question is about inserting text _between_ elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use selenium to get the element right before you want to add the text, then use javascript to insert the text immediately after the end of that element.

For example:

```
node = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='py']")
script = "arguments[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', arguments[1])"
driver.execute_script(script, node, "the new text")
```

Here is a complete working example, assuming that the website has at least one div (which it does at the time I write this):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.example.com")

node = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div")
script = "arguments[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', arguments[1])"
driver.execute_script(script, node, "the new text")
```